# Put new text on the same line in the output file

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a settings file for my. Vbs happens that it also creates settings for my. Bat file and add new text to invest the same place the text on the same line the file creates a new line.

***Ex:***

CBNC-Blacklist =TEST

**When I add a new text with the old it is well**

CBNC-Blacklist =TEST

SDSADADA

```
Sub Main()
  Dim Blist

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("A\a00_Blacklist.ini")
  If objFile.Size > 0 Then
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("A\a00_Blacklist.ini", 1)
    strContents = objReadFile.ReadAll
    objReadFile.Close
  End if

  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = True

  Blist = Inputbox(vbcrlf & "Digite abaixo os itens que você deseja adicionar" & vbcrlf & "na Blacklist separando os mesmos com espaços:", "NoCheating", strContents)

  If Blist = "" Then
    msgbox "A Blacklist NÃO foi alterada!",vbExclamation,"NoCheating"
  Else 
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objMiFichero = objFSO.OpenTextFile("A\a00_Blacklist.ini", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)

    objMiFichero.WriteLine( Blist )

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objMiFichero = objFSO.OpenTextFile("A\a00_Config_2.ini", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)

    objMiFichero.WriteLine( "CBNC-Blacklist="&Blist )

    msgbox "A Blacklist foi atualizada!",vbInformation,"NoCheating"
  End if
End Sub

On Error Resume Next

Main

If Err.Number Then
  WScript.Quit 4711
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I wanted and I have to say it was very difficult anyway thanks for the help and the code below is the code ... I could always read the first line. Ini file and always writes in the first well.

```
Sub Main()

Dim Blist

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("A\a00_Blacklist.ini", ForReading)

For i = 4 to 3
    objTextFile.ReadLine
Next

strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Blist = Inputbox(vbcrlf & "Digite abaixo os itens que você deseja adicionar" & vbcrlf & "na Blacklist separando os mesmos com espaços:","NoCheating",strLine)

If Blist = "" Then

msgbox "A Blacklist NÃO foi alterada!",vbExclamation,"NoCheating"

Else 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objMiFichero = objFSO.OpenTextFile("A\a00_Blacklist.ini", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)

objMiFichero.WriteLine( Blist )

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objMiFichero = objFSO.OpenTextFile("A\a00_Config_2.ini", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)

objMiFichero.WriteLine( "CBNC-Blacklist="&Blist )

msgbox "A Blacklist foi atualizada!",vbInformation,"NoCheating"

End if

End Sub

On Error Resume Next

Main

If Err.Number Then

WScript.Quit 4711

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VBScript doesn't have a "seek" statement to position a file pointer. And you can't combine any of the file modes (`ForReading`, `ForWriting`, `ForAppending`) so that prevents you from "reading" the file until you get to a certain position and then writing at that position. (I've always wondered why they chose bit-position values (1, 2, 8) when you can't combine the values anyway. They could have just used 1, 2, 3).

What you can do, however, is parse your original `ini` file and write to a new one. If nothing should change, just write the original line to the new file. If the value *should* change, write a *new* value to your new file. For example, if you wanted to change the value of `CBNC-Blacklist` from `TEST` to `NEW`:

```
Set FileIn  = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\settings.ini", ForReading)
Set FileOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\settings-new.ini", True)

Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream

    ' Read a line from the original file...
    strLine = FileIn.ReadLine()

    ' Is this the line we want to change?
    If Left(strLine, 15) = "CBNC-Blacklist=" Then

        ' Write the new value to the new file.
        FileOut.WriteLine "CBNC-Blacklist=NEW"

    Else

        ' Just write the original line to the new file.
        FileOut.WriteLine strLine

    End If

Loop

FileIn.Close
FileOut.Close

' Finally, replace the original settings file with the new one...
objFSO.CopyFile "c:\settings-new.ini", "c:\settings.ini", True
```

Of course you could make this more modular by creating a subroutine that accepts the "key" and "value" as parameters. I just wanted to keep things simple for this example.